# How to do I read some tabular data from a text file, into a 2D array ?

Tags: matlab

I have a data file which looks like this:

```
-4.999492 -0.569242 -0.681710 -4.999759 -0.805206 -0.491153 -5.349476 -0.566062 -0.470935
-4.999759 -0.805206 0.491153 -4.906714 -0.686502 0.620194 -4.999492 -0.569242 0.681710
-5.349476 -0.566062 -0.470935 -5.299752 -0.811038 -0.147914 -5.568033 -0.568687 -0.119200
-4.999492 -0.569242 -0.681710 -4.906714 -0.686502 -0.620194 -4.999759 -0.805206 -0.491153
-5.299752 -0.811038 -0.147914 -5.349476 -0.566062 -0.470935 -4.999759 -0.805206 -0.491153
-5.568033 -0.568687 0.119200 -5.568033 -0.568687 -0.119200 -5.299752 -0.811038 -0.147914
```

This is just a small sample. Altogether there are 9 columns and about 1000 rows. I need to import this data into a 2D matlab file, where each cell is storing just one number.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Why don't you start with a simple: `doc load`

Answer (score 0):

The `fscanf` function will probably do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the [import wizard](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/import_export/br5wz4t.html#f5-91134) which does [generate](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/10/05/code-generation-from-import-wizard/) the import code when requested.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few possibilities actually,

```
M = load( 'data.txt', '-ascii' );
M = dlmread( 'data.txt', ' ');
```

And some more functions that can handle more complicated formats.